# Copy remote btrfs incremental snapshot to new drive w/ UUID

Tags: networking, backup, btrfs, uuid

Situation:
Two machines (A & B, with local drives dA & dB) connected via slow network.

Drive dA has initial backup to dB, while locally attached on machine A.

```
btrfs send RO-snapshot-1-dA | btrfs receive btrfsmount_dir_on_dB
```

Machine A/dA sends incremental snapshots to B/dB over slow network.

```
btrfs send -p RO-snapshot-1-dA RO-snapshot-2-dA | ssh B btrfs receive btrfsmount_dir_on_dB
```

This works great.
But now I need to replace the drive dB on machine B with dC.
On machine B:

```
btrfs send RO-snapshot-on_dB | btrfs receive btrfsmount-on_dC
```

but now, from machine A:

```
btrfs send -p RO-snaphot-2-dA RO-snapshot-3-dA | ssh B btrfs receive btrfsmount-on_dC
```

...results in cannot find parent UUID.
Is there a way for me to fix this? (I can change the btrfs partition UUID with `btrfstune`, but this is not capable of altering a subvolume UUID.)

Comment: I "fixed" your second command block to be all one line; if I was wrong to do so, please change it back.